# angular ui router resolve view not loading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state configuration which can be abstracted to the following:

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
    templateUrl: 'myPath.html',  
    resolve:{
         'myData': function($q, myFactoryFirst, myFactorySecond) {
             var data = {};
             data.first = myFactoryFirst.get(1); //returns a resource related to entity 1
             data.second = myFactorySecond.get(2);  //same as above
             return $q.all({first: data.first.$promise, second: data.second.$promise});  
          }
    },
    controller: function($scope, myData){
      console.log(myData);
    }
}
```

When I go to my state, something strange happens. My controller has all of the resolved data inside of it when printed out via the console log, HOWEVER, my view does not load. If I take out the promise, my view loads. It seems that somehow, despite the data being resolved and available to the ctrl, the view is not able to recognize that the data has been recieved. Has anyone run into this issue before?

Comment: That's pretty odd. Does the request for the template come through in the network log?

Comment: Yep, part of the reason it is so frustrating!